# Нужно описывать типы данных в классе, после интерфейса?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Класс Calculator имплементируется от ICalculator, где описаны все методы и их типы, стоит ли повторно это делать для параметров методов класса ? Если уберу, то в метод можно будет передать любой тип. Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно написать, только начал изучать TypeScript

```js
interface ICalculator {
    add(num: number): number;
    subtract(num: number): number;
    multiply(num: number): number;
    divide(num: number): number;
    print(): void;
}

class Calculator implements ICalculator {
    protected _res: number = 0;

    add(num: number) {
        return this._res = num + this._res ;
    }

    subtract(num: number) {
        return this._res = this._res - num;
    }

    multiply(num: number) {
        return this._res = num * this._res;
    }

    divide(num: number) {
        return this._res = this._res / num;
    }

    print(): void {
        console.log(`Currently value: ${this._res}`);
    }
}
let myCalc = new Calculator();

myCalc.add(260);
myCalc.subtract(12);
myCalc.multiply(12);
myCalc.divide(2);
myCalc.print();
```

Comment: Воообще, по идеи надо, да. Потому что если вы не укажете типы, то это будут разные методы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делать это не обязательно.

Однако, если нужна проверка типов, в случае не указания типов параметров в самом классе, придется явно указывать интерфейс в качестве типа переменной:

```
let myCalc:ICalculator = new Calculator();
```

В этом случае, при попытке вызвать метод с несоответствующим типом параметра будет ошибка.

[**Пример на playground**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20ICalculator%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20add(num%3A%20number)%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Calculator%20implements%20ICalculator%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20protected%20_res%3A%20number%20%3D%200%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20add(num)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this._res%20%3D%20num%20%2B%20this._res%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0Alet%20myCalc%3AICalculator%20%3D%20new%20Calculator()%3B%0A%0AmyCalc.add('260')%3B)